# react remix loading dynamic form data

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, dropdown, loader, remix

I have a web application based on remix+react, and I couldn't find information about dynamic data loading, and would like some guidance and referrals please :)
I have a querying system for a sports api. The fields are dropdowns, and the options are determined by the previous selections. For example - if i'd like to query the number of goals a player has scored, I need to specify a year, call the api to get the players that played for the team for that year and process the information to set the options property of the Select component, and only after the user picks a player I can query the api for the final response.
Using hooks to check if state changes and call the api feels wrong with remix, but in the future of my project I am imagining multiple dropdowns relying on data queried an processed by previous selections of the user, and I have no idea how to architecture my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried using hooks to figure out when the state changes and then query the api and provide the options to the next dropdown in the pipeline, but if feels very wrong with remix.